# Adding Exif data to a tif increases the file size

Tags: raw, metadata, gimp, tiff, ufraw

I have some `jpg` images exported from `RAW` files using UFRaw and they are very large in size(>15MB). So, in order to save space, I opened them in GIMP and re-exported as `tif` images with `JPEG` compression and the results were very good, file sizes reduced to about 5MB.
 But since the `tif` images were exported using GIMP, there were no exif data like `Camera Maker`, `Date taken` etc.

I, then, manually added some exif data, this is where things get weird, the file size increase about 5 times the untagged file.

Eg: This is the file size of the original `tif` image, no exif data added:
[image: OriginalImage]

This when `Camera Maker` is added:
[image]

And when `Date Taken` is added:
[image]

Why is there such a huge increase in the file size?
Is there any way to add exif data without increasing the file size?

Comment: Is there a reason that you save files as .tif?

Comment: You are applying lossy compression twice. Never recommended. I think you should reevaluate your workflow.

Comment: @Alex.S Because I wanted to reduce the file size without reducing the image quality. If I export the `jpg` to `tif`with compression, I could do that.

Comment: @osullic I thought `tif` compression is lossless.

Comment: No, you couldn't. TIF with jpeg compression is just a container for a jpeg-file. You could easily save your image as jpeg with the same (and ever a bit smaller) file size and equal quality.

Comment: TIF compression might be lossless, yes. But you save you files with JPEG-compression and jpeg is not losless.

Comment: @Alex.S I don't understand. What do you mean by TIF compression?

Comment: It is not relevant, because you don't use it saving your image jpeg-compressed. Save them as normal jpeg.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58636/discussion-between-rogue-and-alex-s).

Comment: TIFF is a container format, like a ZIP file, with multiple pages.  It is a rather complex format.

Comment: There is no "tiff compression". TIFF files are a container and can store data in various compressions. JPEG compression is the same in whatever container you package it, differences are in the jpeg quality level chosen.

Answer (score 6):

<del>I don't know how you added the exif data, but it could very well be that the application you used for this recompressed the file, and not with jpeg compression.</del>
Windows explorer recompresses a jpeg-tiff as LZW if you edit the metadata, you can see that in the file properties/details tab.

Anyway, if you don't like the size of a jpeg exported from a raw file, the proper way is to export it again, but with a lower quality setting (be aware of possibly visually apparent loss of quality, maybe make some A/B tests to find a good compromise between size and quality.).

The reduction in file size is not from the jpeg->tiff conversion, but because gimp apparently applied a stronger compression, but you can change that directly at the source (UFRaw), too.

Comment: I used the native Windows Explorer to edit the metadata.